# What is a good Jsp IDE

Tags: jsp, ide

I'm a c# developer but have a job that involves some jsp code. 
I've been using notepad++ which does a great job in highlighting but I'm missing the intellisense and find it difficult to find the methods I need.

What is a good jsp IDE for someone coming for C# that has intellisense?

**Update**

I tried eclipse and idea but both interfaces were really different and unfamiliar. So I ended up finishing it in notepad++.

**Update - Netbeans did the job**

Thanks Kibbee. I had some more time and I tried netbeans and it works great with JSP. It was really easy to get it working. 
I [downloaded it](http://www.netbeans.org/downloads/index.html), installed the jsp plugins and I was up and running. It has intellisense and is pretty lightweight.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might want to check out [Netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org/).  From what I remember for Java applications, it had pretty good intellisense support. Although I've never used it for JSP.  From just reading their site, it seems like they do have good intellisense like features for JSP and J2EE web development type things. It's definitely worth a try.

Answer (score 3):

I like [IDEA from Intellij](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) - but I come from the Java side into C#...

Answer (score 2):

This wouldn't be an answer to your question, but don't expec VS-like functionality in the Java world. I'm not saying there are no good systems, I'm saying once you're used to VS, it is very hard to change your thinking about what an IDE should do. Just try out different IDEs and see what suits you best - it's always a personal choice.

Comment: +1 for this: "I'm saying once you're used to VS, it is very hard to change your thinking about what an IDE should do."

Answer (score 1):

I think Neatbeans are better then other IDE that supports JSP, specially for the user who works on MS Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse from IBM would appear to be one of the market leaders, but maybe to much of an entreprise application for what you are doing.

Comment: Eclipse, unlike IntelliJ, doesn't have any intellisense-like capability in JSPs. The BEA (Oracle) Workshop edition does, but it's still inferior to IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

Try myEclipse, it at least have an integrated design view, see if it is of help.

Answer (score 0):

We use [JBuilder](http://www.codegear.com/products/jbuilder) at work and it does a pretty good job. It has intellisense too.