# IDE for jsp and html?

Tags: html, jsp

I would normally use Visual Studio for web development, but I don't think it works with JSP, so I need to use something else - what do you recommend?

I would like to use CSS too.

Comment: Eclipse for Java EE (alternatives: Netbeans (also free), IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate (not free))

Comment: Are you looking for something with just code coloring and maybe source control, or something with an integrated debugger?

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans is nice and its free!

[Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Lot of opinions and experiences were presented [What is a good Jsp IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305056/what-is-a-good-jsp-ide) maybe this could help you.

Answer (score 0):

I just use Notepad++ for everything.  I would recommend Eclipse.

Comment: What I like about Notepad++ is, is that it's so simple to use - netbeans and eclipse are just so confusing.