# Debugging JSP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jsp

Is it possible to debug JSP and javascript codes?

I am a back end developer but for some reason I have to deal with JSP and javascript. I try to put a breakpoint but it doesn't work.

Alert is not an option since I want to see the flow of the code execution.

Comment: May this helps:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609316/debug-javascript-in-eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of JavaScript code you have a few options as most main stream browsers come with JavaScript development tools. These tools provide features such as breakpoints and variable watching.

Some examples are:

- [Firefox Developer Tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools)
- [Firebug addon](http://getfirebug.com/)
- [Google Development Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)
- [Opera Developer Tools](http://help.opera.com/Linux/10.50/en/devtools.html)

I haven't got much experience in JSP myself but friends of mine who do recommend [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/).

You can look further with google or checking out this topic from a previous question here: 
[What is a good Jsp IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305056/what-is-a-good-jsp-ide)

Comment: I don't need other IDE since I am already using Eclipse.
Google Chrome debug tool works fine in JSP and Javascript.